# PFQuery not fetching PFUser in relation with the class

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have tried a PFQuer to fetch the list of messages which have the user in it :

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Message"];
[query whereKey:@"idUser" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
tmpMessages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[query findObjects]];
```

however when I try to access to the user using the fetchInBackGroundWithBlock :

```
 [user fetchInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject * _Nullable object, NSError * _Nullable error) {
     NSLog(@"user= %@ ",[object valueForKey:@"username"]);
}];
```

I get this exception :

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PFRelation fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa540d6d560'
```

I have also tried to incluse the user is the query using `[query includeKey:@"idUser"]` but I get the following exception : `field idUser cannot be included because it is not a pointer to another object`

When I show it using `NSLog(@"user= %@ ",object );` , I get

```
user= <PFRelation: 0x7fa3d85f63b0, 0x7fa3d85f5fd0.idUser -> _User>
```

What should I do to make it work ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `user` object is a `PFRelation`.

They are used to describe many to many relations in Parse.

It sounds like you have set this up possibly with the `PFUser` as the `targetClass`. You can access the objects using the `query` property of the relation.

The code would be like...

```
[relation.query findObjects...
```

Another solution is to change the backend on Parse so that the user property is actually a user object.

On Parse, when you enter the data browser...

If the `user` property looks like this...

[image]

the property is a `PFRelation`.

If the property looks like this...

[image]

the property is a Pointer to the `PFUser` object and so the `user` property will be a `PFUser`.

What does yours say? `Relation<_User>` or `Pointer<_User>`?

Comment: It is a User object on Parse.

Comment: @OmarChaabouni please see my edit. What does your user property say? `Relation` or `Pointer`?

Comment: @OmarChaabouni OK, please see my answer. My initial assumption was correct. Your `idUser` property is actually a `PFRelation` object. You need to use it to then fetch the users.